# mpdf setHTMLFooter not working

Tags: html, footer, mpdf

I'm having an issue with mPDF, I need to put a HTML footer but seems to do nothing. This is my code:

```
$mpdf = new mPDF();
$mpdf->AddPage('L','','','','',5,5,30,20,5,5);
$mpdf->useSubstitutions     = false; 
//$mpdf->simpleTables   = true;
$mpdf->useOnlyCoreFonts     = true;
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader($header,'',true);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter($footer);
//$mpdf->SetFooter($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'|{PAGENO}|'.date(DATE_RFC822)); 

$mpdf->Output($pdfFilePath, 'F');
$mpdf->Output($pdfFilePath, 'I');
```

I'm using AddPage because trying to make a new mPDF() with some params, doesn't put Landscape orientation and other configurations.
This is the $footer var:

```
$footer = '<div class="foot">
    <div id="leyend_foot" class="center">
       <p>&copy; 2014 Grupo Diagn&oacute;stico ... 113 00</p>
    </div>
       </div>';
```

The $mpdf->SetFooter function works fine, but I really needs HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found what's going wrong...
I put some css in the container div, and the *position: absolute* seems to be the problem

Answer (score 0):

> Try to put **setFooter()** before **WriteHTML()**

```
$mpdf->setFooter($footer);
```